# How to trigger call by activating Loudspeaker?

Tags: iphone, call

I am Triggering a call from my App,But I want to trigger a call by  enabling loudspeaker programmatically....

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Phone app is outside your app's sandbox, and it controls its own audio session.  Thus, whatever your app "enables" will be overridden by the user's control of the Phone app.